# Django : Aggregate Sum works on view only after a refresh

Tags: django, sum, http-post, refresh, aggregate-functions

I have an Invoice model in Django that has multiple Line models.(line items that have a title, unit price , and qty)

I have a 'addline' view that allows to add item lines to the invoice.
The view also displays all current invoice lines and a calculated sum of the total price for all line items.

when  I submit a new line item, the view refreshes to the same page and the line item appears properly, but the total (totalservices or totalgoods) of line items is not updated .
It becomes updated when i refresh the page manually , or when i add another line -with the previous line total.

here is my relevant view

```
def addline(request, id):
    form = AddLineForm(request.POST or None )

    invoice = get_object_or_404(Invoice, id = id)
    linelist = Line.objects.filter(invoice = id).order_by('created_at')
    servicelines = linelist.filter(line_type  = "S")
    goodslines = linelist.filter(line_type = "G")
    totalservice = servicelines.aggregate(Sum('line_total'))['line_total__sum']
    print servicelines.aggregate(Sum('line_total'))
    totalgoods = goodslines.aggregate(Sum('line_total'))['line_total__sum']



    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False) #do schtuff with data
        instance.invoice = invoice
        instance.line_total = instance.unit_price *instance.qty
        #print instance.line_total
        if form.cleaned_data.get('overwrite'): 
            invoice.invoiced_service = totalservice or 0 #or zero to prevent fuss if list is empty
            invoice.invoiced_goods = totalgoods or 0
            invoice.save()
        form.save()
        form = AddLineForm()

    context = {'inv': invoice, 'form': form, 'lines':linelist, 'goods': goodslines, 'services': servicelines ,'totalservice' : totalservice, 'totalgoods':totalgoods }
    return render(request,'testpaper.html', context)
```

Thanks in advance, I'm not sure what could be the problem. Maybe that the Sum is lazy and not evaluated ?

*edited to reflect actual view

Comment: what is the view of 'invoice_detail'?

Comment: Ah, I had put that to try and troubleshoot, that line normally is not there  ,it goes directly. 
form.save()
  `form = AddLineForm()
  return redirect('invoice_detail', id)
 context = {'inv': invoice, 'form'`

Comment: can you post te original so? please

Comment: I edited the original , thanks

Comment: did you try get it from inv.invoiced_goods?

Comment: also note that you dont call instance.save() after commit=False

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem : the 'if form.is_valid 'block that ends in form.save() needed to be before the block that calculates lines , otherwise lines are calculated before current item has been saved .